# Selecting Multiple Rows from DataGridView using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I'm trying to select multiple rows from a `DataGridView` instead of iterating with a for-each loop.

I can select 1 item using this code:

```
DataGridViewRow row2 =
     (from DataGridViewRow r in dgView.Rows
     where r.Cells["name"].Value.ToString().Equals("Akins Ford")select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

But when I try to select multiple rows, using this code:

```
List<DataGridViewRow> rows2 =
      (from DataGridViewRow r in dgView.Rows
       where r.Cells["status"].Value.ToString().Equals("active")select r);
```

I got an error:

> Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)   C:\Software\Json\Json\Form1.cs  188 18  Json

Comment: Could you try, instead of .FirstOrDefault() try .ToList()?

Comment: I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error

Comment: Could you try this.... `dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(x => x.Cells["status"].Value.ToString() == "active").ToList().ForEach(x => x.Selected = true);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a simple wrap around the result:

```
List<DataGridViewRow> rows2 =
        new List<DataGridViewRow>
        (from DataGridViewRow r in dgView.Rows
         where r.Cells["status"].Value.ToString().Equals("active")
         select r);
```

This is because the linq code returns an `IEnumerable<T>` and not `List<T>`. But you can create a `List<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>` by calling the appropriate constructor:

```
var list = new List<T>(iEnumerable);
```

To prevent null reference exceptions you might want to further improve your code thus:

```
List<DataGridViewRow> rows2 =
        new List<DataGridViewRow>
        (from DataGridViewRow r in dgView.Rows
         where r.Cells["status"]?.Value.ToString().Equals("active")??false
         select r);
```

I am assuming that you are using VS2015 which allows null propagation

```
r.Cells["status"]?.Value.ToString().Equals("active")??false
```

putting the '?' after the `Cells["status"]` ensures that  any null references result in a null. And then the final `??false` says, that if we had a null we return false (ie don't include this row).

Comment: or just use `ToList`

Comment: The code compiles, but I get the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You probably have an exception inside the where clause. Is it possible that the Cell's value can be null?

Comment: Yes, I do have a row that can be null - that fixed it. Thanks!